# Autoscaling on Insufficient Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

We have ECS services with autoscaling configured. Workflow of autoscaling should be like this:

- if in 1 minute we receive more than 10 values we need scale up
- wait 10 minutes
- if no values we need to scale down

Scale up works perfect but scale down doesn't work at all. We are getting this:

```
Failed to execute action arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-central-1:BLA-BLA-BLA-fargate-scale-down. Received error: ""
```

Probably this is because in terraform for `resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "down"` we have the following:

```
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = ""
      metric_interval_upper_bound = 0
      scaling_adjustment          = -100
    }
```

and it expects "0" instead of no data.

In `resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cloudwatch_metric_alarm_down"`:

```
  treat_missing_data = "breaching"

  insufficient_data_actions = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.down.arn]
```

Is there any solution for this? Except once per minute manually send "0".

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do also - did you find solution for that?

Comment: Not yet. I asked the same question on AWS forum but also no any reply.

Comment: Is this it?  Looks like it got answered https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=956586&#956586

Comment: Yes. So it has been answered. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cloudwatch_metric_alarm_down" {
  alarm_name          = "${local.name}-ecs-alarm-down"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = var.evaluation_periods_down
  threshold           = var.downscale_threshold

  metric_query {
    id          = "e1"
    expression  = "FILL(m1, 0)"
    label       = "0 if NoData"
    return_data = "true"
  }

  metric_query {
    id = "m1"
    metric {
      metric_name = var.metric_name
      namespace   = var.env_name
      period      = "60"
      stat        = var.metric_statistic
    }
  }

  alarm_actions = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.down.arn]

  depends_on = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.down]
}
```

More about FILL() is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#metric-math-syntax-functions-list